# Is Azure table storage partition key only query is optimized?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Table storage documentation says that the tables are indexed on partition and row keys and there are 4 types of queries sorted based on their performance (Point, Row Scan, Partition Scan, Table Scan). But it is a bit unclear what category does the Partition Key only query falls in. So if my query has one filter "PartitionKey eq SomeKey" is the indexing optimized and this will be as fast as point query (apart from the fact that it will return much more results)? Or the indexing does not allow that and it will be a partition scan or some other type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a partition scan. If the partition key is determined in filter but row key isn't, all the entities throughout the whole partition have to be scanned.